# How to upload an Google App Engine App for different users

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dev-appserver

Having created a python appengine app and now want to distribute to different "users" who need to run their app on their own appid / account. What is the best way to handle this?
Up to 10 users I can do this for the users, but how can I package the app for them, or do it for them?

Answer (score 1):

GAE is a cloud system where you'd normally create one app to serve multiple clients. See [Multitenancy and the Namespaces API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/overview) to see how to safely separate your clients data. Also you can have [multiple custom domains](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain) so that every client can have a separate domain.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of multitenancy and Namespaces, but there are users who really want to have their own version of the source code.

Comment: Then maybe you should give them war archive and they should upload it to their own instance?

Comment: Yes, this is my second best guess also. I was just curious, if there is an easier way. Maybe a python script, which is doing most of the _work_ like setting up some config and putting and appid into the source and so on.

Comment: It's possible to upload the war to 3rd party account, but this is not documented. See Codenvy: https://codenvy.com/features. They support deploy to GAE: https://wiki.codenvycorp.com/display/CPD/Google+App+Engine. Also see this: http://try.devtable.com/